# Where does ubuntu store the address for the global proxy?

Tags: boot, networking, system-installation, filesystem, proxy

When you install an ubuntu server it asks:
"If this system requires a proxy to connect to the internet, enter its details here."

I decided to try throwing in a random local address with the default squid port of 3128

When it booted, the proxy address worked when I tried apt-get update...(i know because it wasnt able to connect)

**My question is**: I'm not sure where to find the config file for setting up the proxy address? I've tried going through and finding it in etc/environment, etc/default/proxy(not a real thing it turns out) and etc/apt. Nothing shows up in the config file for 'etc/environment'. 'apt.conf.d/apt.conf' and 'etc/default/proxy' don't exist. **So where does it store this address for the global proxy?**

Ive also checked nftables and iptables, there are no rules specifying the port of the proxy server...

Answer (score -1):

In 22.04, the two files:

```
/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/90curtin-aptproxy
/etc/systemd/system/snapd.service.d/snap_proxy.conf
```